# New "View Order" button in Google Mail

Tags: gmail, amazon

Just checked my email after making an order at Amazon.com and saw a small "View Order" button in the subject line. I tried to look up whether this is a new feature or not but couldn't find anything.

Does anyone know about this feature and Google Mail does this for other orders? Do you know if it's possible to set up an email message sent to Google Mail so that it adds this button?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's based on a initiative called Schema.org. Google announced this feature for Gmail in May 2013: http://gmailblog.blogspot.dk/2013/05/take-action-right-from-inbox.html

Quotes from the post (emphasis and linkifying mine):

> Email is an important part of how we get things done -- from planning an event with friends to organizing that family vacation to Costa Rica. And today, getting those things done is getting a little easier with **new quick action buttons in Gmail**, designed to help you tackle your digital to-do’s as quickly as possible.

... and ...

> **These buttons appear next to certain types of messages in your inbox and let you take action on an email without ever having to open it**. For example, you can RSVP to your friend's party invitation or rate that restaurant you went to last night all right from the inbox. You’ll be checking things off that to-do list in no time.

... and ...

> **If you are a developer and want to add actions to your emails**, check out http://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a documentation from Google for Email markup with examples
https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/order

It is possible to use JSON or HTML microdata.
Hope it helps.